# Ubuntu RAID failure [get a warning]

Tags: server, hard-drive, raid

Okay I might sound paranoid, but every day I think that my harddrives in both my servers failed for some reason and I am going to lose all my data.

I have a server with a RAID 5 installation with Ubuntu [Pretty sure it's hardware RAID]

I also have another server with RAID 1 [Pretty sure it is software RAID even though I have to enter the RAID in the BIOS, but during the installation Ubuntu asks to activate Serial ATA RAID]

Is there any ways to monitor both RAID's and maybe make the servers beep or send me an e-mail in an easy way?

Also the server with the RAID 1 runs EXTREMELY faster than the one with the RAID 5, is it because of the RAID or is it because of something else?

Thanks so much!